# SaveData is not output and instanceRef null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with react-editor-js library. I'm trying to get data from it, but it doesn't output and when I check instanceRef it's null. Here is the code.

```
const Create = () => {
    const instanceRef = React.useRef(null);
    let data = { '1': 'test' }

    async function handleSave() {
        const savedData = await instanceRef.current.save()
        console.log(savedData)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Header Name='Создание'/>
            <Menu/>
            <div className="editor">
                <ReactEditorJS
                    instanceRef={(instance) => (instanceRef.current = instance)}
                    tools={EDITOR_JS_TOOLS}
                    data={data}
                    onChange={() => handleSave}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

If I use

```
onChage={() => handleSave}
```

I get this error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'save')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please double-check `instanceRef ` function been called by `ReactEditorJS `

`<ReactEditorJS instanceRef={console.log} />` check is it logging ref or not.
if not there is some problem in ReactEditorJS component itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per `ReactEditorJS` docs - you should use `onInitialize` to save your instance on initialize.

So in your case try this -

```
const Create = () => {
    const instanceRef = React.useRef(null);
    let data = { '1': 'test' }

    async function handleSave() {
        const savedData = await instanceRef.current.save()
        console.log(savedData)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Header Name='Создание'/>
            <Menu/>
            <div className="editor">
                <ReactEditorJS
                    //changed instanceRef to onInitialize
                    onInitialize={(instance) => (instanceRef.current = instance)}
                    tools={EDITOR_JS_TOOLS}
                    data={data}
                    //need to add '()' to call handleSave
                    // or you can change it to onChange={handleSave}
                    onChange={() => handleSave()}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

References -
[How to access editor-js instance?](https://github.com/Jungwoo-An/react-editor-js#how-to-access-editor-js-instance)

Note - I have not tried this solution but by reading the documentation I have added this answer, let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm a little confused.

Comment: confused about what?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I guess I didn't say it right.